# How to refactor this Ruby code to check for valid paramaters?

Tags: ruby, exception, error-handling, refactoring

Is there a better (more eloquent) way to check for valid params?

```
def load_data filename, start_percent, end_percent
  raise 'Values must be [0,1]' if start_percent < 0
  raise 'Values must be [0,1]' if end_percent   < 0
  raise 'Values must be [0,1]' if start_percent > 1
  raise 'Values must be [0,1]' if end_percent   > 1
  ...
```

Ruby 1.9.3

EDIT: `start_percent` and `end_percent` are supposed to be floats.

Comment: What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: It's redundant, takes up a lot of space, and is error prone. Besides that it looks amateurish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this error happens, you'll want to know the details (what kind of error, what argument, what invalid value):

```
def load_data filename, start_percent, end_percent
  raise ArgumentError, "start_percent must be [0,1]; received #{start_percent}." unless start_percent.between?(0, 1)
  raise ArgumentError, "end_percent must be [0,1]; received #{end_percent}." unless end_percent.between?(0, 1)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah! Depends if you want integers only or also decimals

```
# decimals
def load_data(filename, start_percent, end_percent)
  accepted = (0..1)
  unless accepted.cover? start_percent && accepted.cover? end_precent
    raise 'Values must be [0,1]'
  end
end
```

integers:
change to `accepted = [0,1]` and `accepted.include? start_percent` and for `end_percent` too

References:

Range#cover: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F

Range#include?: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-include-3F

Array#include?: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F

Answer (score 1):

Compact version :

```
[start_percent, end_percent].each{|p| raise 'Values must be [0,1]' unless (0..1).cover?(p) }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def load_data filename, start_percent, end_percent
  unless (0..1).include?(start_percent) and (0..1).include?(end_percent)
    raise 'Values must be [0,1]' 
  end
  ...
```